# Pyton matplotlib.pyplot.scatter для KNN

Tags: python

Подскажите как нарисовать KNN, у меня дата-фрейм с 17 колонками, везде инфа как создать двух мерный рисунок распределения, мне бы 17ти мерный отобразить, подскажите пожалуйста как. scatter просит х и у  но куда еще то 14 разместить для отображения? Или подскажите как вообще можно визуализировать KNN.

Comment: можете уточнить что именно вы хотите нарисовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите визуализировать точки в более чем 3х-мерном пространстве, то вам придется сначала уменьшить размерность до двух или трехмерного пространства.

Я бы посоветовал попробовать [t-SNE алгоритм](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) - он очень хорошо кластеризирует похожие точки в многомерных пространствах и в итоге после работы алгоритма t-SNE получаем кластеры схожих точек.

Итоговый выбор алгоритма для уменьшения размерности будет зависеть от исходных данных и от результата, который вы хотите получить.

[Здесь есть неплохое сравнение 6 алгоритмов.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dimensionality-reduction-algorithms-with-python/)

Comment: Понял спасибо, да скорей всего это то что надо, а средства для визуализации точек в 3х мерном пространстве на python подскажите?

Comment: Пакетом, предназначенным для работы с трехмерными графиками, является mpl_toolkits.mplot3d. Смотрите здесь: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых.  Вообще-то говоря kNN -  это алгоритм. Как можно его нарисовать-визуализировать?  Еще раз - "визуализировать алгоритм" ???

Теперь про попытки что-то нарисовать в 17- мерном пространстве. Понятно, что это какая-то мягко говоря странная идея. Всякие квази-многомерные диаграммы, типа радарных -  хороши при пол десятка объектов, потом на них что-то понять невозможно. Да и вообще - если вы действительно построили классификатор кNN - он работает вне зависимости от того, нарисовали вы его или нет.

В общем, какой-то кашеообразный вопрос. Попробуйте его переформулировать так, что-бы можно было хотя-бы понять, зачем вам понадобилось делать то, что в принципе  сделать нельзя, да еще для задачи, где то, что вы хотите сделать -  имеет практически нулевой смысл.

Comment: Да я ток учу python и алгоритмы sklearn'a извините что 'криво' выражаю мысль но я научусь и уверен смогу говорить употребляя верную терминологию, и корректно отобразить поставленную задачу. Спасибо за ответ!)